# Probability of choosing value of variable in equation - 4 tuple ($x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4=10$)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

It may be the wording in this problem that is throwing me off but I can't seem to figure out the number of possible successful outcomes to calculate the probabiliy:

**Suppose a non-negative integer solution to the equation $w+x+y+z=10$ is chosen at random (each one being equally likely to be chosen). What is the probability that in this particular solution that $w$ is less than or equal to 2?**

Let $A = w \leq 2 $

To find P(A) I need:

\begin{align}
P(A)=\frac{|E|}{|S|}
\end{align}

Where |E| = Successful outcomes and |S| = Size of sample space.

I start by finding the sample space of possible solutions, since this is a 4 tuple: ${\{w,x,y,z\}}$ --  order does not matter and repeats are allowed,  I would say the size of sample space is

\begin{align}
|S| = C(10+4-1,4) =C(13,4)
\end{align}

So this gives me:

\begin{align}
P(A)=\frac{|E|}{C(13,4)}
\end{align}

However, I can't seem to figure out $|E|$ as I don't know how to account for all cases...

I am *guessing* since there are 4 variables: $\{w,x,y,z\}$ and we assume $w$ is aleady chosen from the following: $\{0,1,2\}$ (since $w\leq 2$) this leaves us with 3 variables left to determine. The number of outcomes for this would look like:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
case & \text{Number of outcomes} \\
\hline
0+x+y+z= 10  & C(10+3-1,3) = C(12,3) \\
1+x+y+z= 10  & C(10+3-1,3) = C(12,3)\\
2+x+y+z= 10  & C(10+3-1,3) = C(12,3) 
\end{array}
$$

This feels wrong.. or maybe I am overthinking it. But would the solution be:

\begin{align}
P(A)=\frac{3 \cdot C(12,3)}{C(13,4)}
\end{align}

Comment: The idea looks okay to me, but I see some mistakes. E.g. $1+x+y+z=10$ means that $x+y+z=9$. There are $\binom{11}2$ solutions. Also $|S|=\binom{13}3$ (not $\binom{13}4$). There are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ nonnegative integer solutions for $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$. Not $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

Comment: I would rather make the order matters in the sample space since it will somewhat matter in the event space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put w = 0

Find solution for $x+y+z = 10$ and that is ${12\choose2}=66$

Put w = 1

Find solution for $x+y+z = 9$  and that is ${11\choose2}=55$

Put w = 2

Find solution for $x+y+z = 8$  and that is ${10\choose2}=45$

Add the above cases to a total of $166$

For all non negative w,x,y,z

Find the solution for $w+x+y+z = 10$ and that is ${13\choose3}
=286$

Thus the probability $=\frac{166}{286}$

Comment: This makes the most sense to me, I am just struggling to understand why/when you are using $C(n+r-1, r-1)$ as opposed to $C(n+r-1, r)$ to find $w+x+y+z=10$

Comment: For all cases, I have used only C(n+r-1,r-1).  I do not know of an instance when you could use C(n+r-1,r). In the first three cases,  it is C(10+3-1,3-1),C(9+3-1,3-1),C(8+3-1,3-1) and in the last case it is C(10+4-1,4-1)

Answer (score 2):

There is almost certainly a better way to do the problem than this, but this is a straightforward method.

We can list out all the non-negative integer solutions to $w + x + y + z = 10$, assuming that $w,x,y,z$ are nondecreasing. We list the number of permutations for each solution, and the probability that $w \leq 2$.

Order from the most zeroes to the fewest:

---

\begin{align*}
10&=0 + 0 + 0 + 10 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with } 4 \text{ permutations) } &\, \text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&=0 + 0 + 1 + 9 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with } 4 \cdot 3\text{ permutations) }&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 0 + 2 + 8\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with } 4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 0 + 3 + 7 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with } 4 \cdot 3\text{ permutations) }&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&=  0 + 0 + 4 + 6\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with } 4 \cdot 3\text{ permutations) }&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&=  0 + 0 + 5 + 5 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with } \binom{4}{2}\text{ permutations) }&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 1 + 1 +8\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 1 + 2 +7\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4! \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 1 + 3+6\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4! \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 1 + 4 +5\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4! \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 2 + 2 +6\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 2 + 3 +5\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4! \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 2 + 4 +4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 0 + 3 + 3 +4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,1 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 1 + 1 +7\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 1 + 2 +6\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 1 + 3 +5\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 1 + 4 +4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }\binom{4}{2} \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 2 + 2 +5\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \cdot 3 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 2 + 3 +4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4! \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 1 + 3 + 3 +3\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,1 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 2 + 2 + 2 +4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }4 \text{ permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,3 \text{ out of } 4\\
10&= 2 + 2 + 3 + 3\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ (with }\binom{4}{2} \text { permutations) } &\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ prob } w \leq 2 \text { is } \text{:}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,2 \text{ out of } 4\\
\end{align*}

---

The total number of permutations is:

$$(4\cdot 3)\cdot 11+(4)\cdot 4+(4\cdot 3/2)\cdot 3+(4\cdot 3\cdot 2)\cdot 5 = 286$$

Multiply the number of permutations by the probability that $w \leq 2$ for each case. Add these numbers up. Divide by the total number of permutations. We get $$\frac{166}{286} = \boxed{\frac{83}{143}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Against a total number of solutions of $\binom{10+4-1}{4-1} = 286,$

we exclude impermissible ones by initially assigning $3$ in $w$, so only $7$ more are left to assign,

thus permissible ways are $\binom{10+4-1}{4-1}- \binom{7+4-1}{4-1} = 166$

Proceed to compute the probability

Comment: Can you explain why you use 13C3 instead of 13C4 for total number of solutions? I understand the stars and bars example but don't know how to differentiate C(n+r-1, r-1) [yours] from C(n+r-1, r) [mine]

Comment: @DatumPlane: Another name for stars and bars is balls and bins. Here there are 10 balls and 4 bins. Note particularly that we need only **3** dividers to depict 4 bins, e.g. $\circ\circ|\circ\circ\circ|\circ|\circ\circ\circ\circ$ to depict 2|3|1|4 The number of dividers needed is *always* one less than the number of bins